# Scala filter by type parameter and return construct return type with type constructor

Tags: scala

I have the following working code

```
case class FilterType[A](t: GenTraversable[A]) {
  def filterType[B](implicit tag: ClassTag[B]): GenTraversable[B] = t.flatMap {
    case element: B => Some(element)
    case _          => None
  }
}
```

With this definition I am able to filter the following as expected

```
trait Demo
case class Demo1(a: String) extends Demo
case class Demo2(a: Int)    extends Demo

val input: Seq[Demo]              = Seq(Demo1("hello"), Demo2(2))
val output: GenTraversable[Demo1] = FilterType(input).filterType[Demo1]
```

I would like to improve on that and take a **type constructor** as a parameter as well so that instead of returning a `GenTraversable` I can return the same type as `input` (in this case a `Seq`). My attempt was the following

```
case class FilterType2[T[_]: GenTraversable, A](t: T[A]) {
  def filterType[B](implicit tag: ClassTag[B]): T[B] = t.flatMap {
    case element: B => Some(element)
    case _          => None
  }
}
```

However I'm getting the following compilation errors:

```
Error 1: type T takes type parameters
Error 2: value flatMap is not a member of type parameter T[A]
```

Comment: `GenTrasversable` is not a typeclass, if you want to use that approach you may be interested in **cats** `Functor`, otherwise take a look to: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html _(and adapt the code or google for a `2.12-` approach)_ - BTW, note that filtering by class may not always work as expected due type erasure - and finally, it would have been simpler to use `collect` instead of `flatMap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first error:

`GenTrasversable` is not a context/typeclass. You are expecting a subclass of `GenTrasversable`, not a context of that, so you should use `<:` instead of `:`.

For your second error:

`flatMap` does not belong to `GenTrasversable`. It belongs to `GenTraversableLike`: [doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html#flatMap%5BB%5D(f:A=%3Escala.collection.GenTraversableOnce%5BB%5D):scala.collection.GenTraversable%5BB%5D)

Working code:

You also need `CanBuildFrom` in Scala 2.12 for constructing a generic collection.

```
case class FilterType[T[A] <: GenTraversableLike[A, T[A]], A](t: T[A]) {
  def filterType[B](implicit tag: ClassTag[B], bf: CanBuildFrom[T[A], B, T[B]]): T[B] = t.flatMap {
    case element: B => Some(element)
    case _          => None
  }
}
```

Full code: [code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JzNNiiikTIua4aEUjYqfXg)

Comment: It would be better to use `collect` than `flatMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You are right in that.